# Android Studio how to update module

Tags: android, android-studio

I made a library and added to my other project as module. The library is not perfect and I have to change some stuff there sometimes. But the changes are not seen in my other project and I have to delete the module and add them again.
Is there an other way to hold the module up to date all time I make changes there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar situatuon some time ago when I had to extract some code from my project and make a library which will be shared between the old and a new projects. I'm using Mercurial to store the codebase, so it was natural to use [subrepositories](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository) for this purpose.
Basically, subrepository is a *nested* repository which is used by some *main* repository. Whenever I make the change in the subrepo, I commit it, push to the bitbucket repo, and after that I can run `hg pull` and `hg update` from the main repo (I prefer pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> from Android Studio). Every time you update the *nested* repo, *main* repo stores the info about the subrepo revision currently used in the `.hgsubstate` file, so if you want to try something out in the old revision of your project, Mercurial knows which *subrepo revision* it has to use with this old version.
Similar functionality can be found in Git also. I don't know about other vcs with the subrepository support (wasn't interested in them).